# Simulate hover then click to trigger the already set onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Gmail, if you clicked to select a message, this will show a bar on top of the messages table, to perform mass actions on the selected messages (please see the attached GIF photo).

[image: Gif photo]

I'm trying to click the delete icon at this bar, but, I can't do that, because, its markup changes once you hover it.

Its first draw at the DOM is like this:

```
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji nX T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs mA" act="10" title="Delete" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <div class="asa">
        <div class="ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And once you manually hover it, it changes to be like this:

```
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji nX T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs mA" act="10" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Delete" aria-label="Delete" style="user-select: none;">
    <div class="asa">
        <div class="ar9 T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To select it, I use its first markup, like this:

```
let $delBtn1 = $('[title="Delete"]'); 
let $delBtn2 = $('[data-tooltip="Delete"]');
```

But, I can't perform the click at it and make it trigger its `onclick` function, because, I guess it listens to the onclick event AFTER a manual hover at it first.

How can I trigger the manual hover at it then trigger a click?

I tried to do:

```
$($delBtn1).mouseenter(); 
$($delBtn1).trigger('mouseenter');
$($delBtn1).mouseover(); 
$($delBtn1).trigger('mouseover');
$($delBtn1).mouseup(); 
$($delBtn1).mousedown(); 
$($delBtn1).focus();
$($delBtn1).select();
```

None of this worked!

Even tried to wait:

```
$($delBtn1).mouseenter();
setTimeout(function () {
    $($delBtn2).click();
}, 1000);
```

I'm trying this through a Chrome extension and through the console, and both doesn't work!

Any direction how can I trigger its `onclick` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using the [`dispatchEvent()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), like this:

```
let mouseoverEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
let mousedownEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
let mouseupEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});

document.querySelector('div[title="Delete"]').dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);
document.querySelector('div[data-tooltip="Delete"]').dispatchEvent(mousedownEvent);
document.querySelector('div[data-tooltip="Delete"]').dispatchEvent(mouseupEvent);
```